# How do I check my Apple Watch model?

Tags: apple-watch

A while back I received an Apple Watch as a gift. I can’t tell whether or not the Watch is an original First Generation or a Series 1.

How do I check which model of Apple Watch I have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The engraving on the back of the watch will tell you. The original Apple Watch just has ‘Watch’ engraved and is sometimes called “Series 0” since it is one generation earlier than “Series 1”. All subsequent watch models have ‘Watch • Series x’ where x is the series of the watch.

> [image]
>   [image]

Click to enlarge.
Left: Apple Support [How to find the serial number or IMEI for your Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204520)
Right: 9to5Mac [Top new Apple Watch Series 1 and Series 2 features](https://9to5mac.com/2016/09/19/top-new-apple-watch-series-1-series-2-features-video/)

You can also look up the model number on the [Identify your Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204507) Apple Support page. You can find the model number in the iPhone Watch app under My Watch → General → About.

Comment: Funny thing to brand it as [|F8FF|Watch](https://i.imgur.com/301Kbol.png)

Comment: @Kroltan Welcome to Unicode [Private Use Areas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas), where [Apple’s put a logo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonts_on_Macintosh#The_Apple_logo)

Comment: Yes, it was one of my notably poor attempts at humour.

Comment: Relevant: *[How can I display the  (U+F8FF, Apple logo) character on Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/1205451/358766)*